# in rails3, How can i customize the subject line in device confirmation mails.only for resend confirmation mail only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation-email

I am using devise for user authentication in my application.and here is the doubt i am having is,How to change subject line for devise confirmation mails. i want to change the subject line only for resend confirmation mails.

Comment: Hi! I was writing an answer to you question about old passwords, but you deleted the question before I could post an answer, and you have no email address on your profile so I write this comment on one of your other questions instead. Anyway: You could save a couple of old password-hashes and try to compare them with the new password. If it is a match, then reject the password change.

Comment: @some,hi..thank u so much.but, the problem is how can i get the current password of that user.

Comment: Please send me an email (you will find the address on my profile)

Comment: @some, i can't able to see your email address in your profile.only these three bio,visits,stats are visible for me.